# How to do a Min and Max of date but following the changes in price points

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm not really sure how to word this question better so I'll provide the data that I have and the result that I'm after.

This is the data that I have

```
sku  sales  qty  date
A    100    1    1-Jan-19
A    200    2    2-Jan-19
A    100    1    3-Jan-19
A    240    2    4-Jan-19
A    360    3    5-Jan-19
A    360    4    6-Jan-19
A    200    2    7-Jan-19
A    90     1    8-Jan-19
B    100    1    9-Jan-19
B    200    2    10-Jan-19
```

And this is the result that I'm after

```
sku  price  sum(qty)  sum(sales)  min(date)  max(date)
A    100     4        400         1-Jan-19   3-Jan-19
A    120     5        600         4-Jan-19   5-Jan-19
A    90      4        360         6-Jan-19   6-Jan-19
A    100     2        200         7-Jan-19   7-Jan-19
A    90      1        90          8-Jan-19   8-Jan-19
B    100     3        300         9-Jan-19   10-Jan-19
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the min and max date of each price point, where price = sales/qty. At this point, I can get the min and max date of the same price but I can separate it when there's another price in between. I think I have to use some sort of `min(date) over (partition by sales/qty order by date)` but I can't figure it out yet.

I'm using Redshift SQL

Comment: can you please elaborate on the result based on the input. It is very hard to interpret the above result

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands query.  You can do this by generating a sequence and subtracting that from the date.  Then aggregate:

```
select sku, price, sum(qty), sum(sales),
       min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sku, price order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by sku, price, (date - seqnum * interval '1 day')
order by sku, price, min(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `Sub Query` and `LAG`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0368038802c26e1080991c34268c5171)**

```
SELECT SKU, Price, SUM(Qty) SumQty, SUM(Sales) SumSales, MIN(date) MinDate, MAX(date) MaxDate
FROM (
      SELECT SKU,Price,SUM(is_change) OVER(order by SKU, date) is_change,Sales, Qty,date
      FROM (SELECT SKU, Sales/Qty AS Price, Sales, Qty,date,
                    CASE WHEN Sales/Qty = lag(Sales/Qty) over (order by SKU, date) 
                    and  SKU = lag(SKU) OVER (order by SKU, date) then 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_change
            FROM Tbl
     )InnerSelect
) X GROUP BY sku, price,is_change
ORDER BY SKU,MIN(date)
```

**Output**

[image]